# Colour detection on click event.

Tags: java, gwt

In my project GWT Java, I need colour detection on click event. When user clicks any where in program window, I need to detect the colour of click point(x,y). How it is possible. Where as keeping in view that there may be no one image in the program window. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to take a screenshot, and then determine the color information of the pixel at that particular location in the captured image. A little Google-ing turned up this gem: [html2canvas - Screenshots with JavaScript](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

I haven't used it though, so I can't give you any more help than that, unfortunately.